# UWP Transparent blur effect with WinJS

Tags: javascript, uwp, winjs

I'm a newbie with UWP and I'm trying to realize an app with the new 
[Blur Background effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47nuh.jpg)

Is there any way to make it with a js project?

Comment: I don't know what that screenshot has to do with your question, but what file manager is that in your screenshot?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak On the left site of the screenshot there is the blur effect.

Comment: @schumi1331i see no blur at all in that image.

Comment: I believe the question is refering to https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/8232264-enable-blur-and-transparency-xaml-effects-to-allow. Which is implemented and documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition. The documentain does not describe how to use it from JavaScript. However, the API can be used in JavaScript. I'm not sure how to create a similar effect on the window though.

Answer (score 0):

The new blur background effect (Fluent Design acrylic material) can be mimicked to some extent in a WinJS project using CSS gaussian blur (`filter: blur(10px);`) and a noise texture overlay.

However, you of course cannot make the actual window transparent to see the desktop underneith this way.

See examples: [CSS-only Acrylic Material from Fluent Design System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522299/css-only-acrylic-material-from-fluent-design-system)